# Binding to an ancestor property inside an animation in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpf-animation

I have a WPF page with a TabControl in it, and I wanted to design the tabs to have a nice underline when selected and on mouse hover.

I've managed to do that but each tab has a different length, and it seems that I can't bind a property of the TabItem inside of its animation.

This is what i have done so far:

```xml
<TabControl Width="{Binding ActualWidth,
                ElementName=cnvsMain}" Height="{Binding
                ActualHeight, ElementName=cnvsMain}"
                        BorderThickness="0" >
                <TabControl.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabItem">
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <Border Name="Border"
                                            BorderThickness="1,1,1,0"
                                            BorderBrush="Gainsboro"
                                            CornerRadius="6,6,0,0"
                                            Margin="2,0">
                                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                                                          VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                          HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                          ContentSource="Header"
                                                          Margin="10,2"/>
                                        </Border>
                                        <Label Name="TabUnderline" Background="LimeGreen"
                                               Margin=" 5, 0" Height="5" Width="0"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                                            Storyboard.TargetName="TabUnderline"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                                                            From="0" To="100"
                                                            Duration="0:0:0.1"
                                                            AutoReverse="False" />
                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                </BeginStoryboard>
                                            </Trigger.EnterActions>
                                            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                                            Storyboard.TargetName="TabUnderline"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                                                            From="100" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.1"
                                                            AutoReverse="False" />
                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                </BeginStoryboard>
                                            </Trigger.ExitActions>
                                        </Trigger>
                                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </TabControl.Resources>

                <TabItem Header="Rooms">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Label Content="TODO: List all rooms" />
                        <Label Content="TODO: Create room button" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </TabItem>
                <TabItem Header="Statistics" />
                <TabItem Header="Details" />
            </TabControl>
```

It works great but there is one simple flaw:
The under line will always be 100 pixels (Or is it units?) wide, and each tab has its unique and different width. I've tried to replace the hard-coded 100 to `{Binding ActualWidth}` or using a RelativeSource to get the width of the TabItem, but I keep getting an exception everytime this page is being loaded because of a binding-error.

How can I bind a TabItem's property to a value inside its own animation? Is it even possible?

Comment: A `Storyboard` is frozen for performance reason and it cannot be frozen if you bind the `To` property. The obvious solution to your issue would be to define handle the `SelectionChanged` event for the `TabControl` and create the animation dynamically on the fly instead of creating a `Storyboard` in the XAML markup.

Comment: Use a scaletransform and animate the scalex from 0 to 1. Set that to 0 initially using a style. I'd suggest a rectangle rather than label.

Comment: Very often it turns out to be much faster and easier to code your animations that to make them in the XAML. It is significant more complicated than to code it in C#

But the advise given by @Andy to use a scaletransform instead is good, but if you make your animation in C# it does not matter, because there you can set an animation to change any property